# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ending April 2019 then what next one needs to do and how on dual boot win7

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ending April 2019 then what next one needs to do and how. I would also like to know if we can directly jump to the higher release or upgrade step by step? If step by step then how to upgrade to the latest, please suggest. I would again like to opt for LTS. I am scared to do as grub should not get crashed..

Worth noting is i have dual boot with Win 7 ultimate.

Regards,
SHK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) and [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: I would like to go through step by step, not an issue, but only thing i am scared of is that i have dual boot system and not sure what to care while upgrade to 16.04 and to 18.04 LTS....

Comment: Do you have backups of all your personal files?

Comment: yes I am backing up of all personal files from Ubuntu before the jump. Don't want to get in a situation where my system goes down and nothing works...

Comment: Make sure you have a bootable USB stick or something. It is very rare that Ubuntu updates will make your system unbootable and it would always be fixable using a bootable USB stick.

Comment: USB Stick with 18.04? I have one with 14.04. Please suggest.

Comment: Can someone confirm the iso file name for 32bit ...